# LCD 5 XPT2046 Touch screen and Raspberry Pi 3 B+

Tags: ubuntu-mate, touchscreen, raspberrypi

I'm running Ubuntu MATE 18.04 on Raspberry Pi 3 Model B+ and it works fine, but I need to install a touch screen.

I followed [the steps here](https://www.elecrow.com/wiki/index.php?title=HDMI_Interface_5_Inch_800x480_TFT_Display) and restarted the system  but it gets stuck on the rainbow screen.

Any suggestions?

Thanks in advance

Comment: Ubuntu MATE is on-topic official flavor, but Raspberry is off-topic here. Try to ask on http://ubuntu-mate.community/ or https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/ .

Comment: Both of the above comments are wrong about the scope of this site. Ubuntu MATE is an official flavor and questions about running it on any device are welcome here. Your question is on topic (although hardware recommendation requests are indeed not allowed), though you may find [raspberrypi.se] has more experts on this. Apologies for any confusion. cc @N0rbert

Comment: Ubuntu MATE is [on topic](https://askubuntu.com/questions/206407/how-do-i-find-out-which-version-and-derivative-of-ubuntu-is-right-for-my-hardwar/518968#518968).

Answer (score 0):

For me 5" touchscreen LCD for Raspberry pi 3 B+ works fine( touch and display). Just copy and past this command below to your config.txt on your boot file. No need to install its driver. Just reboot your raspberry pi (ubuntu mate) then it work fine.

```
--- added by elecrow-pitft-setup  ---
hdmi_force_hotplug=1
max_usb_current=1
hdmi_drive=1
hdmi_group=2
hdmi_mode=1
hdmi_mode=87
hdmi_cvt 800 480 60 6 0 0 0
dtoverlay=ads7846,cs=1,penirq=25,penirq_pull=2,speed=50000,keep_vref_on=0,swapxy=0,pmax=255,xohms=150,xmin=200,xmax=3900,ymin=200,ymax=3900
display_rotate=0
--- end elecrow-pitft-setup  ---
```