# How get LCD-3.5 touch screen working on PI 4b? Ubuntu 20.04 server

Tags: drivers

Rpi 3.5 inch Touch screen
Raspberry Pi 4B
Ubuntu 20.04 server with unity desktop

How install screen driver so that it use lcd instead hdmi display? Can Ubuntu 20.04 server use rpi 3.5 lcd touch screen?

Comment: What is the display model? How does it [look like](https://www.waveshare.com/wiki/3.5inch_RPi_LCD_(A))?

Comment: It is 3.5inch Rpi Display 480x320 Pixel with XPT2046 Touch Controller. It connects directly to Pi 4b (no cable).

Comment: Have you tried https://askubuntu.com/a/1192627 ? Or found any other solutions?

Answer (score 1):

This githib page details an extremely easy method to use
https://github.com/victorbrca/waveshare35-rpi3b-ubuntu-20.04-64